Identify a book about travellers in a desert telling stories
It was a book I read somewhen 2010 to 2020 from one of the numerous Soviet publications of adventure novels and stories collections or an imitation thereof (borrowed from one of my then-friends' home library, I believe; it is not--or at least was not--uncommon to find books like that around the neighbourhood); I believe it was not an original Russian work, but rather a translated one, most likely from English (my best guess is that the story is set in America).
I remember but a select few details; it might be that part A is an opener from a different book. The novel/story (not quite sure about its size) itself is of the adventure genre akin to some of the works of, say, Jules Verne or Jack London, and while I read it as [relatively speaking] a child, the parts that I remember imply an adult target audience (although you can never be sure with those old adventure novels).
A) (Not connected to the rest of the plot) There was a rather short myth-like opener that went as follows: There were pilgrims at the desert, who at one point in their travel stopped and quarrelled so much that God turned them to stone. Now it is but once a year (or maybe not, or maybe it was related to a specific date such as Christmas) that they come back to life--just to quarrel more and to be turned back to stone.
B) A part of the main plot was that some travelling characters told their stories, yet I remember but one. It was of a doctor (a surgeon, I believe) who was

 tricked into murdering a woman as follows: he was told it was a family tradition to decapitate the dead before burial, but in actuality the woman was not dead; for some reason it also was that the whole operation was performed in the dark. Then, only the help of a lawyer friend who studied some old cases and found a precedent saved the doctor from the death penalty, instead leaving him with an amputated arm (or hand, my memory is not too clear).

Then it is revealed that one of the co-travellers has been the man who

 tricked the doctor all that time ago, and he (I believe) explains his story and reasoning.

He (or someone else) was also wearing a mask, I think, but cannot remember the reason.
C) A minor detail that I think also relates to that book is that in the beginning there was a discussion of the severity of different deserts, and the travellers expressed different opinions on the question of the most harsh desert.
Now, I am not sure that is even the main plot line. However, one similarly fuzzy memory of mine had been resolved to an actual book not that long ago, which led me to believe my recollections as mostly true.
I have asked a number of people, including my mother who has read a fair amount of those adventure publications since her childhood. All to no avail.
